# How to Access and Modify Variables from Different Classes in Java

Tags: java

This question may look like it's been asked million times, and that's because it has. Unfortunately, and maybe this is just my fault but I don't think so, it has not been thoroughly and accurately answered. I have been looking for a while to an answer to this question and come across many ambiguities and am now looking for an actual good answer. In my research I have seen the following: "Use static variables, never use static variables, use a getter and a setter, getter's and setter's are evil, global variables do not exist in Java, make it a public variable, public variables should not be used" and more. All I'm wanting is to have a variable that has a value that can be accessed and changed from multiple class and these multiple classes can all see the changes made to the variables value. How is this possible and which is the best way of doing it?

Comment: @John3136 After looking at tutorials on the net and other questions here I come upon the mentioned ambiguities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a heap of different ways, and it really just depends on how secure you want the variable to be. I tend to use getters and setters simply because it's much easier to track method calls than it is a change of variable.

If it's a class whose sole purpose is to hold values in variables then you might just want to use direct variable calls, but if they are values in a more functional class you would probably use getters and setters.

Comment: So for variables that are first declared and defined in one class but need to be changed and accessed from another class, you prefer getters and setters? Thanks, this may be the way I go.

Comment: The reason why you use getters and setters is because you can change the behaviour of a getter or setter (e.g. give it error checking or side effects) but you can't change the behaviour of a raw field access.

Comment: Yeah, that makes perfect sense. It's just that I have read multiple things about all the different ways being the best/only way to do it and then something else about different ways being the worst way to do it.